# Condition for embedding a matrix space to another matrix space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb F), \mathbb M_m(\mathbb F)$ be the space of all matrices of order $n,m$ respectively. Suppose $f\colon\mathbb M_n(\mathbb F)\to\mathbb M_m(\mathbb F) $ is an injective ring homomorphism (i.e. $f$ preserves addition, multiplication and unit(multiplicative identity) ). Prove that: $n\mid m$.
My thought: I found that if $n\mid m$, then
$$ g\colon \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{F})\to\mathbb{M}_m(\mathbb{F}),X\mapsto\text{diag}[\underbrace{A,A,\ldots,A}_{m/n\text{ terms}}].$$
is a . So I guessed that the homomorphism should have the form like $g$. But I have no idea to prove this. Moreover, I'm not sure whether there is an counter example or not.

Comment: Indeed, $X\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} X & 0 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is an injective ring homomorphism $g\colon M_n(K)\rightarrow M_{n+1}(K)$. And certainly neither $(n+1)\mid n$ nor $(n+1)\mid n$ (you have both mixed up).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Here I need the ring homomorphism keeps the multiplicative identity. Sorry for my omission.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Here I need the ring homomorphism keeps the multiplicative identity. Sorry for my omission. And I fixed the wrong switch.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Do you mean that $\mathbb F= \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z$? I think this holds. Thank you! But what if we set $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb F=\mathbb C$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde If $f\colon X\mapsto=\begin{pmatrix} X & 0 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is a ring homomorphism, it should satisfy $f(X+X)= \begin{pmatrix} 2X & 0 \cr 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $. So this is not right for some fields.

Comment: OK. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know modules this is easy. The matrix ring $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb F)$ is semisimple with a unique simple module $\mathbb F^n$. If we have a (unital) ring homomorphism $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb F)\to\mathbb M_m(\mathbb F)$, then the module $\mathbb F^m$ for the ring $\mathbb M_m(\mathbb F)$ becomes a module for the ring $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb F)$, so is a direct sum of $t$ copies of $\mathbb F^n$. Comparing dimensions we see that $m=nt$, so that $n$ divides $m$.